# How to set Amcharts 4 scrollbar color?

Tags: reactjs, amcharts, amcharts4

I am trying to set scrollbar color in Amcharts, but none of the options specified on Amcharts site has worked.

I am using "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.2.2" in react app.

I have tried many options which are mentioned below. None of them are working.

```
chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();
chart.scrollbarX.fill = "#017acd";
chart.scrollbarX.setFill(new am4core.color("#017acd"));
chart.scrollbarX.setStroke(new am4core.color("#017acd"));
chart.scrollbarX.stroke = "#017acd"; //this sets the border line color of 
scrollbar.
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 14):

A scrollbar has a [background](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/scrollbar/#background_property), a [thumb](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/scrollbar/#thumb_property), a [startGrip](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/scrollbar/#startGrip_property) and an [endGrip](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/scrollbar/#endGrip_property). Each of them can be styled individually by :

```
chart.scrollbarX.background.fill = am4core.color("#017acd");
chart.scrollbarX.thumb.background.fill = am4core.color("#017acd");
chart.scrollbarX.startGrip.background.fill = am4core.color("#017acd");
chart.scrollbarX.endGrip.background.fill = am4core.color("#017acd");
chart.scrollbarX.stroke = am4core.color("#017acd");
```

You can create different states for all the components to set different colors for `hover` or `press` (`down`).

```
chart.scrollbarX.thumb.background.states.getKey('hover').properties.fill = am4core.color("#017acd");
chart.scrollbarX.thumb.background.states.getKey('down').properties.fill = am4core.color("#017acd");
```

I created [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZvzxE) code pen to show you a complete example.

If you want to style not a single scrollbar, but all the scrollbars in your app I would suggest [creating a custom theme](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/creating-themes/) for that.

```
function am4themes_myTheme(target) {
  if (target instanceof am4core.InterfaceColorSet) {
    target.setFor("secondaryButton", am4core.color("#6DC0D5"));
    target.setFor("secondaryButtonHover", am4core.color("#6DC0D5").lighten(-0.2));
    target.setFor("secondaryButtonDown", am4core.color("#6DC0D5").lighten(-0.2));
    target.setFor("secondaryButtonActive", am4core.color("#6DC0D5").lighten(-0.2));
    target.setFor("secondaryButtonText", am4core.color("#FFFFFF"));
    target.setFor("secondaryButtonStroke", am4core.color("#467B88"));
  }
  if (target instanceof am4core.Scrollbar) {
    target.stroke = am4core.color("#017acd");
  }
}

am4core.useTheme(am4themes_myTheme);
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WmzmQj) is a code pen showing a theme example.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide such a detailed answer. It was really helpful.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you.